# Procedimiento de SQL Server siempre devuelve int

Tags: sql, sql-server

Si ejecuto el siguiente código en [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server), no sé por qué siempre el procedimiento devuelve `int`, ya probé todo y no encuentro donde esta el problema.

Obviamente, cuando quiero ejecutar el codigo me devuelve:

> "error al intentar asignar 'ok' a un int"

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[INSERTAR_SUBDIR_resolucionesSAD]
    @Directorio VARCHAR(MAX),
    @SubDirectorio VARCHAR(MAX),
    @dev varchar(10) output
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @result as varchar(10)
    DECLARE @MainFolderPath AS HIERARCHYID
    --You must have the given below file table (dbo.DataBank)
    --and directory (IT) inside file table in the existing database.
    SELECT @MainFolderPath= sadSql.dbo.resolucionesSAD_ft_v.path_locator   FROM sadSql.dbo.resolucionesSAD_ft_v
    WHERE [unc_path]= @Directorio

    DECLARE @SubDirectoryPath2 varchar(max)
    EXEC dbo.GetNewPathLocator
      @MainFolderID=@MainFolderPath
    , @SubDirectoryPath = @SubDirectoryPath2 OUTPUT

    if (@MainFolderPath IS not NULL  )
        begin
        INSERT INTO dbo.resolucionesSAD_ft (name,path_locator,is_directory,is_archive)
        VALUES (@SubDirectorio, @SubDirectoryPath2, 1, 0)
        set @dev = 'ok'
        end 
     else
         set @dev = 'not'

   return   @dev

END
```

Si ejecuto el procedimiento me sale esto, observen que la variable return_value tiene

```
USE [sadSql]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int,
        @dev varchar(10)

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[INSERTAR_SUBDIR_resolucionesSAD]
        @Directorio = N'C',
        @SubDirectorio = N'D',
        @dev = @dev OUTPUT

SELECT  @dev as N'@dev'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Comment: ¿Qué tal si al ejecutar el *stored procedure* cambias `@dev = @dev OUTPUT` por `@dev OUTPUT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ## Devolver datos con un código de retorno:
>
> Un procedimiento puede devolver un valor entero, denominado código de retorno, para indicar
> el estado de ejecución de un procedimiento. Se especifica el código de
> retorno para un procedimiento mediante la instrucción RETURN. Al igual
> que con los parámetros OUTPUT, debe guardar el código de retorno en
> una variable cuando se ejecute el procedimiento a fin de usar su valor
> en el programa de llamada.

Por ejemplo, al ejecutar el siguiente procedimiento obtendrás:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE PROCEDIMIENTO
    @PARAMETRO VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN    
    SELECT @PARAMETRO = 'CADENA'
    RETURN 1
END

DECLARE @PARAMETRO VARCHAR(10); 
DECLARE @RESULTADO INT;
EXEC @RESULTADO = PROCEDIMIENTO @PARAMETRO OUTPUT

SELECT @RESULTADO, @PARAMETRO
```

> ```
> +---+--------+
> | 1 | CADENA |
> +---+--------+
> ```

Pero en caso quieras devolver un valor diferente a un entero, te arrojará un error.

Por ejemplo, modificando:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE PROCEDIMIENTO
    @PARAMETRO VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN    
    SELECT @PARAMETRO = 'CADENA'
    RETURN 'ABC'
END

DECLARE @PARAMETRO VARCHAR(10); 
DECLARE @RESULTADO INT;
EXEC @RESULTADO = PROCEDIMIENTO @PARAMETRO OUTPUT

SELECT @RESULTADO, @PARAMETRO
```

Obtendrás el error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ABC' to data type
> int.

---

**Referencia:**

- [Devolver datos de un procedimiento almacenado](https://docs.microsoft.com/eS-Es/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure)